# c++ quickfix failure to send

Tags: c++, quickfix

I'm having an unexpected issue with a c++ quickfix client application using FIX 4.4.  I form marketdatarequest and populate it and then call send which returns true.  The message is not found in the message or event log files.
No error seems to be reported - what could be happening?

```
FIX44::MarketDataRequest request(FIX::MDReqID(tmp)
        , FIX::SubscriptionRequestType('1')
        , FIX::MarketDepth(depth)); // 0 is full depth
FIX::SubscriptionRequestType subType(FIX::SubscriptionRequestType_SNAPSHOT);
FIX44::MarketDataRequest::NoRelatedSym symbolGroup;
symbolGroup.set(FIX::Symbol(I.subID));

request.addGroup(symbolGroup);

FIX::Header &header = request.getHeader();
header.setField(FIX::SenderCompID(sessionSenderID));
header.setField(FIX::TargetCompID(sessionTargetID));


if (FIX::Session::sendToTarget(request) == false)
    return false;
```

My FixConfig looks like:

```
[DEFAULT]
HeartBtInt=30
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
ConnectionType=initiator
UseDataDictionary=Y
FileLogPath=logs
[SESSION]
FileLogPath=logs
BeginString=FIX.4.4
DataDictionary=XXXXX
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
TargetCompID=tCompID
SenderCompID=sCompID
SocketConnectPort=123456
SocketConnectHost=XX.XX.XXX.XX
SocketConnectProtocol=TCP
StartTime=01:05:00
EndTime=23:05:30
FileLogPath=logs
FileStorePath=logs
SocketUseSSL=N
```

thanks for any help,
  Mark

Comment: `SocketConnectPort=123456` Is this really the port you use ? The largest port number is *65535*. Were you successful in establishing a session with your counterparty and logged in ? Check if you are able to login at all, that should be your first step to confirm if you can send any further messages.

Comment: The port is a place holder - my client is able to connect, log in , and heartbeat with no problems.

Comment: I finally resolved this overnight - I was sending these messages before the logon handling was complete.  Movement of the logic into the onLogon callback resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Mark, just couple of notes not really related to your question but which you may found useful:

1. you dont have to explicitly set TargetCompId/SenderCompId for each message, engine will do it for you.
2. Do not place logic into callbacks(like you did with market data subscription in onLogon). Better create additional thread which will consume events from you listener, make decisions and take an action.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but these should go in comments and not as an answer.

Comment: Thank you rimas,
  I like the callback shifting to thread but it raises further questions for me.   
 What is the lifecycle of the messages passed in a callback?  
 Are they destroyed when the callback regains control?  If this is the case, I would have to make a copy of the data before the leaving the callback and hand that copy to the background worker thread(s).

Comment: Yes, they will be destroyed outside the callback. I suggest keep logic outside of any onMessage because of performance issue.